# Can't send sku on contact form

Tags: magento-1.8, email, ce-1.8.1.0, forms, sku

My intention is to send the sku as a hidden variable when applying for the contact form but only after having visited a product.

It works fine with localhost, where the cache is disabled, but not with the online website because it only gets the information the first time I access to the contact page and when I access from another product it maintains the previous sku. It only works when I refresh the cache but it's really strange in my opinion.

Here is the code I have for form.phtml

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['sku'])) 
    {
        $print_text = $_GET['sku'];
    }
    else
    {
        $print_text = "";
    }
?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $print_text ?>" name="sku" id="sku" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Sku') ?>"/>
```

And this for view.phtml

```
<p>Para cantidades inferiores o informaci&oacute;n <a href="http://example.com/contacto/?sku=<?php echo $_product->getSku() ?>">consultar</a></p>
```

And I get the information from the admin panel, transactional emails. Adding this at the end of the contact form:

```
<p>Sku: {{var data.sku}}</p>
```

How can I get the information without having to refresh cache the whole time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better idea to use  this code for getting sku

```
$print_text=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('sku');
```

I guess your contacts us  url may be `http://example.com/contacts`
 instead of  `http://example.com/contacto`

Comment: Same thing happens. After changing `$_GET['sku']` to `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('sku')` it still has the same value it had before, it doesn't change after having changed the parameter, only if chache is refreshed... :/
Thanks for your help anyway, and what you mentioned about contacts instead of contacto both work

Comment: Never mind, you were right, even when contacto and contacts redirect to the same form, if I put contacts on the link instead of contacto the parameter returns the information correctly.